# Supporting hyperplane of a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $r>0$ and $\overline{B}(0,r)$ be the closed ball of center $0$ and radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its usual norm.

Let $a$ be such that $\left\|{a}\right\|=r$. Consider the hyperplane $$H=\left\{{x:x\cdot \dfrac{a}{\left\|{a}\right\|}=\left\|{a}\right\|}\right\}.$$

I want to prove that $H$ is a supporting hyperplane of $\overline{B}(0,r)$, in other words I want to prove that

$$\overline{B}(0,r)\subset \left\{{x:x\cdot \dfrac{a}{\left\|{a}\right\|}\le\left\|{a}\right\|}\right\}.$$

But I have been unable to prove this. I tried the following:

Let $x\in\overline{B}(0,r)$. It would be equivalent to proving that $x\cdot a\le \left\|{a}\right\|^2=a\cdot a$, or $(x-a)\cdot a\le 0$. I think something could be done from here but I don't know how.

Any hints? Thank you.

Comment: You have $||x|| \leq r = ||a||$. Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson oh of course, thank you for that and the fast response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping $f(x) = x \cdot a$ is a linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence its kernel is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and passes through the origin.  This kernel, it helps to think, is the orthogonal complement of $a$.

Let's prove that $H$ is a translate of $\ker f$ by $a$; i.e., that
$$
H = a + \ker f.
$$
Before we go for it, note that $f(a) = ||a||^2$.

Now, let's show that $H$ is contained in $a + \ker f$.  To see this, suppose $y \in H$. Now let
$$
z = y - a.
$$
(Here, it helps to stop and sketch the above.)  It follows that $f(y) = ||a||^2$, and therefore
$$
f(z) = 0,
$$
so $z$ lies in $\ker f$, so $y$ lies in $a + \ker f$.  We have shown that $a + \ker f$ contains $H$.

To show the containment in the other direction, note that for every $z$ in $\ker f$, we have
$$
f(a + z) = ||a||^2,
$$
so $(a + z)$ lies in $H$.

Now, it is fairly straightforward to show that the closed ball $\overline{B}(0, r)$ is contained in the closed half-space $f \leq ||a||^2$ and intersects $H$ at just one point, namely $a$.